# Java API for creating Ranger Policy

Tags: security, hadoop, authorization

Is there any Java API available for creating Ranger HDFS/Hive Policy?

I am planning to creating policies for logged in user dynamically using Java , so if anyone could point me to java doc?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to make http calls to the rest API of Ranger. A very good list of useful API endpoints is available [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@ranger.incubator.apache.org/msg00064.html). Hope this helps !